How to set a constant color to an object
I am trying to make an object that renders in a constant solid color, independent on lighting or shadows. I tried setting the object surface as Emission with strenght=1. The result depends on blender version, tried in  v3.6 and v4.2 and got different results, neither looked like I expected.

For example with color set to #FF0000 this is what I got in both blender versions and the result I expect to see when rendering. (Expected image made with inkscape)

is there a way to achieve the expected color? v3.6 seems like a darker version of the same color, but v4.2 seems to be messing up the colours to make it "whiter"?
EDIT: I've just realized in v3.6 i was using strength=3, and incrementing strength will reach a similiar color and then start to look whiter, but anyways I would prefer to set a color and know it will be that exact color I set and not having to play arround with strenght value. This does not work in v4.2.

In Scene settings, Color Management, View Transform: choose “Standard”. Works for me.

is there a way to change the "view transform" in only one object? Supose I have this cube i want to render all in a single color but all the other objects keep the "filmic" view transform style.
